# excel macro using variable to define range of a integer failure

Tags: excel, vba

I am making an integer `myrng1` that is defined by

```
Set myrng1 = Range("B3 :" & Cells(LastRow, 2))`
```

in the code

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set myrng1 = Range("B3 :" & Cells(LastRow, 2))
Set myrng2 = Range("D3 :" & Cells(LastRow, 4))

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(myrng1,RC[-1],myrng2)"
Range("B15").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B15:B30"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("B15:B30").Select
```

However what ever I do, I come across `Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed` Error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is

```
Set myrng1 = Range("B3:B" & LastRow)
```

Else if you want to follow your approach then as Bernard mentioned, use the `.Address` property.

Change your code to

```
Set myrng1 = Range("B3:" & _
                   Cells(LastRow, 2).Address( _
                                             rowabsolute:=False, _
                                             columnabsolute:=False) _
                   )
```

or this which does the same thing.

```
Set myrng1 = Range("B3:" & _
                   Replace(Cells(LastRow, 2).Address, "$", "") _
                   )
```

Also I hope you have declared `LastRow` as `Long` and not as `Integer` as you may get an overflow error in xl2007+

One last thing. Your `Cells` object is not fully qualified which can give you error. Fully qualify them. For example (Notice the DOTS)

```
Set myrng1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:B" & LastRow)
```

or

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set myrng1 = .Range("B3:" & _
                       .Cells(LastRow, 2).Address( _
                                                  rowabsolute:=False, _
                                                  columnabsolute:=False) _
                        )
End With
```

**EDIT Thanks to pnuts for pointing this out**

Once you solve the above problem, you will face more problems. For example `"=SUMIF(myrng1,RC[-1],myrng2)"`. Anything between the `"` will be considered a string. You may want to use this instead

```
"=SUMIF(" & myrng1.Address & ",RC[-1]," & myrng2.Address & ")"
```

Again, you may want to use `.Address` without the "$" as mentioned above.

One more thing. If row 30 is the `lastrow` then you can fill the formula in all the cells in one go instead of using `AutoFill` See this Example

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("B15:B30").Formula = "=SUMIF(" & _
                                        myrng1.Address & _
                                        ",A15," & _
                                        myrng2.Address & ")"
End With
```

Or

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("B15:B" & lastrow).Formula = "=SUMIF(" & _
                                        myrng1.Address & _
                                        ",A15," & _
                                        myrng2.Address & ")"
End With
```

Furthermore, I would like to draw your attention to this [INTERESTING READ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select) :p

Comment: Hi there, very grateful for the help you have given me, however whenever i try to run the editted secition, it is giving me a runtime error 1004, application defines or object defined error. any help??

Comment: Can you update your question with the latest code that you are using? Also let us know which line is giving you the error

Answer (score 1):

If the content of `Cells(LastRow, 2)` is not a valid cell reference (like B3 is), the method will fail.

If you want to use the address of `.Cells(LastRow, 2)`, then replace it with `.Cells(LastRow, 2).Address(rowabsolute:=False, columnabsolute:=False)`.

EDIT: You could also use `.Address` with no parameter but you would get something like $A$1 (absolute referencing).